# npm install hangs on Google Cloud Compute Engine VM

Tags: node.js, npm, medusajs, medusa

I'm trying to get a [Medusa backend](https://docs.medusajs.com/development/backend/install) to run on a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM. When running `npm i --verbose` the command always hangs with the last line printed being:

```
reify:@swc/core-darwin-arm64: http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk
```

I have tried the following with no luck:

1. Changing npm (and node) versions
2. Deleting the `node_modules` folder and re-running `npm i`
3. Clearing the npm cache
4. Disabling ipv6 on the VM

The GCE VM has an external IP address and is able to `wwget google.com` so it's not a connectivity issue. The same command runs fine on my Chromebook (Crostini)

Any ideas as to what might be causing `npm i` to hang indefinitely (or at least for a very long time)?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the VM was running out of resources (CPU I believe). An e2-micro VM is not enough. After upgrading to e2-medium things started to work.